# Ошибка: there is already an open DataReader...

Tags: c#, sql

Привет ХэшКод, у меня есть код

```
private void btnAddAdv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textUrl.Text == "" || numBalance.Value == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Заполните все поля", "Системное сообщение");
        }

        else
        {
            MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
            try
            {
                cnt.Open();

                MySqlCommand command = cnt.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE username='" + textUserName.Text + "' and pass='" + Convert.ToString(textPassword.Text) + "'";
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["balance"]) <= 0 && Convert.ToInt32(reader["balance"]) < Convert.ToInt32(numBalance.Value))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Недостатовно средств", "Системное сообщение");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MySqlCommand balancecmd = cnt.CreateCommand();
                        balancecmd.CommandText = "SELECT balance FROM t_user WHERE username='" + textUserName.Text + "' and pass='" + Convert.ToString(textPassword.Text) + "'";
                        balancecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        MySqlCommand cmd = cnt.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE t_user SET balance = balance - 50 - '" + numBalance.Value + "' WHERE username='" + textUserName.Text + "' and pass='" + Convert.ToString(textPassword.Text) + "'";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        MessageBox.Show("Сайт добавлен", "Системное сообщение");
                    }
                }
                cnt.Close();
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.Message, "Системное сообщение");
            }

        }
```

Этот код должен сравнивать значение из Базы Данных и если они больше нуля и больше чем значения элемента numBalace, выводить сообщение что на балансе не хватает средств... иначе сделать тот код что в блоке else, но у меня ошибка

**There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first**

Comment: попробуй закрыть подключения после катч блока

Comment: Тоже самое :(

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил... кому нужен исправленный вариант, держите

```
 private void btnAddAdv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textUrl.Text == "" || numBalance.Value == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Заполните все поля", "Системное сообщение");
        }

        else
        {
            MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
            try
            {
                cnt.Open();

                MySqlCommand command = cnt.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE username='" + textUserName.Text + "' and pass='" + Convert.ToString(textPassword.Text) + "'";
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["balance"]) <= 0 && Convert.ToInt32(reader["balance"]) < Convert.ToInt32(numBalance.Value))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Недостатовно средств", "Системное сообщение");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MySqlCommand balancecmd = cnt.CreateCommand();
                        balancecmd.CommandText = "SELECT balance FROM t_user WHERE username='" + textUserName.Text + "' and pass='" + Convert.ToString(textPassword.Text) + "'";

                        MySqlCommand cmd = cnt.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE t_user SET balance = balance - 50 - '" + numBalance.Value + "' WHERE username='" + textUserName.Text + "' and pass='" + Convert.ToString(textPassword.Text) + "'";

                        reader.Close();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        balancecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Сайт добавлен", "Системное сообщение");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.Message, "Системное сообщение");
            }
            cnt.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: цикл while сработает лишь раз, следовательно while здесь не нужен. А если у меня будет несколько аккаунтов на проверку, тогда у меня будет MySqlException

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всегда использовать подобную вещь

```
using (cnt)
{
    cnt.Open();
    // ...
}
```

Это гарантирует что после каждого обращения к connection оно будет закрыто
И лучше не использовать глобальные переменные а создавать локальную

```
using (var connection = new SQLCinnection(_connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    // ...
}
```