Ошибка: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."
У меня два класса репозитория, у которых есть следующие методы GetAll:
public IEnumerable<Passport> GetAll()
{
    List<Passport> passwords = new List<Passport>();
    using (MySqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection())
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Passports;", connection);

        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string series = reader.GetString(1);
                int number = reader.GetInt32(2);

                passwords.Add(new Passport(id, series, number));
            }
        }
    }

    return passwords;
}

public IEnumerable<Client> GetAll()
{
    List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
    using (MySqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection())
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Clients;", connection);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string surname = reader.GetString(1);
                string name = reader.GetString(2);
                string middlename = reader.GetString(3);
                int passportId = reader.GetInt32(4);

                PassportRepository passportRepository = new PassportRepository();
                Passport passport = passportRepository.GetById(passportId);
                clients.Add(new Client(id, name, surname, middlename, passport));
            }
        }
    }

    return clients;

}

При попытке вызова метода GetById (по сути он вызывает GetAll и ищет элемент по полю Id), я получаю ошибку "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." при попытке создать reader MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();.
Я понимаю, что не могу вызвать reader на соединения на который уже вызван reader, как я могу получить информацию из бд через метод GetAll у passportRepository, при этом не отказываясь от DataReader?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/68903/220553 (также дубликат читайте)

Во втором методе используйте JOIN таблиц Clients и Passports. Таким образом данные будут получены из БД всего одним запросом - это намного эффективнее, чем выполнение множества запросов.

@AlexanderPetrov, Данные методы находятся в разных классах-репозиториях, каждый из которых работает отдельно с каждой таблицей, не хочется делать такой костыль только для того, чтобы получить информацию о клиентах и их паспортах, т.к. проект подразумевает наличие ещё нескольких похожих связей, и придётся везде делать похожую реализацию.

Выкиньте свои никчёмные репозитории и используйте один репозиторий, в котором реализованы правильные sql-запросы.

single resposibility?

Доводите SRP до абсурда: репозиторий на каждую колонку таблицы.

Репозиторий предназначен для абстрагирования от способа хранения данных. Используя репозиторий мы можем не знать, где и как он хранит данные: в реляционной СУБД, в документной, в ключ-значение, в графовой или ещё какой БД, или просто в файлах, причём неважно в каком формате: xml, json, csv или бинарном. А у вас уши SQL торчат: во втором методе второй репозиторий используется для связи по id. Попробуйте заменить способ хранения, например, на файлы. Не получается? Значит выкидывайте нынешнюю реализацию репо и делайте нормальную.
